# Gemfire/geode native client configuration for failover

Tags: c#, gemfire, geode

I want my gemfire data configured as multisite WAN using gateways to 2 sites. 
NY and LON. using:
http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/topologies_and_comm/topology_concepts/multisite_overview.html#topic_70045702D3994BC692E75102CE01BD7C

I can understand how my cluster and locators will work and know about each other.

But how do I configure my native .net client to failover from NY to LON in case NY site goes down.

I will have 4  data node and 3 locators in NY.
I will have 4  data node and 3 locators in LON. With sync from NY->LON.

If I configure my client cache xml to point to NY locators, would they have any information to failover to LON locators?
Is there anything in client cache configuration which can make them aware of LON locators in case NY locators are down?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a full data center outage, you would usually push out new locator info to your NY clients.  Otherwise, you could include your LON locator info with your NY info. The client will connect to the first locator in the list. When that locator is not available or is really busy, it will use the next in the list. So, you will *usually* be ok. However,  you risk your NY clients connecting with the LON locators in case of a network blip or longer GC's or machine busy times. In that case, your NY clients might complain of "slow response time" due to the latency.  It is a good practice to manually fail over the clients.